# How would I stop panels from erasing rectangles I've drawn when I scroll down?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, draw

I'm coding a charting control in C# for the .net framework. I basically have a split panel where I write the names on one side and draw rectangles on the other for the actual graph portion of the control. However, I've realized that every time I scroll down, it erases the part of the rectangles that go out of the panel's view. How do I prevent this?

Side question, how do I make the scroll bar for the second panel work for both. I'm fairly new to some of this stuff so I apologize if anything here is fairly elementary or already answered. Thanks for your time!

Comment: You're not supposed to draw outside your view. If I'm misunderstanding, you will have to [post code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your problem.

Comment: I'm not trying to draw outside of view. I'm drawing onto the panel but then scrolling down, thus bringing the rectangle out of view. The problem is that when scrolling back up, the drawings dissapear

Comment: Show the drawing code! How can we help when we don't see what you are actually doing?? (I hope you are using the Paint event and not CreateGraphics !?!?)

Answer (score 0):

Funnily enough, the answer to your question about scrolling will actually solve the drawing problem. The solution is to add a 3rd panel with `AutoScroll` set to true. Then place your existing two panels inside that one. Don't dock them, but rather set them to their full size. The parent panel's scrollbar will scroll both and instruct them to repaint as needed.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18718476/5097178). It's better to derive your own class from Panel and draw on that.

For future reference, when you are drawing directly on an `AutoScroll` panel, use `TranslateTransform` to account for the scrolling. This solves the drawing issue for me:

```
private void Panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(panel1.AutoScrollPosition.X, panel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y);

    // draw something...
}
```